# Questions about phonegap

Tags: php, cordova, jquery-mobile, build

I built a mobile website using jquery mobile (client side) and php/mysql (server side) 
I found phonegap to put it in a native app. But despite many researches, i didnt found the answer for those questions :

- how do phonegap loads pages in those two cases :
  When the page refreshes without ajax 
  When a jqm page is loaded and injected with ajax

This question is crucial because if the page is loaded from my server, i would be able to put php into it. If pages are stored and brought directly from the client where the app is installed, I have to remove all php from my pages. On the other side, storing pages on the client would improve drastically the speed of the loading.
The best would be to choose for each ajax call of jqm, by a parameter, whether the first or the second scenario. Controlers written in php and returning json would be loaded from the server each time, but the jqm pages would be stored into the client phone as he download the app.

I have a second question:i ve downloaded the phonegap desktop app but i still dont know how to build an entiere app sendable to the stores. I found several technologies like phonegap build, do you recomand it ? i dont know a word in java..

Thanks for your help and please excuse me if Im wrong with english sometime.

Comment: You cannot package a website which is built in PHP for PhoneGap, but you can create a website using HTML / CSS / JavaScript (crucially including AJAX) which can then send requests to PHP pages (which are externally hosted) and use that data to modify the website client-side. Basically if you write your website in a properly RESTful way it will work.

Comment: Like EM-Creations indicated I can confirm that if you make REST calls to your backend website and fetch json back your PhoneGap application will work just fine.  I used jquery + jquery mobile within my app to make things easier.  I just finished my app in just under a month.

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to tell phonegap to bring some pages from the servers and other from the user phone ?

Comment: For ex. My jqm pages would be loaded from the user phone, and the php script returning json, from the server. But the both are still ajax request,    So i need a parameter of sth in the url to tell phonegap where to go